# Is there a label smoothing version for multi-label classification?

Tags: classification, categorical-encoding, multilabel

I use label-smoothing for multi-class single label classification as follows.

```py
import torch


def label_smoothing(gt: torch.tensor, alpha: float = 0.1) -> torch.tensor:
    """Adds smoothing to one-hot encoded target vector.

    Parameters
    ----------
    prediction
        Vector with predicted probabilities (is only required to get the 
        total number of classes).
    gt
        Target labels (one per sample).
    alpha
        Smoothing parameter.

    Returns
    -------
    smoothed
        The smoothed labels.

    """
    assert gt.ndimension() == 2, 'target should be one-hot encoded'
    k = gt.size(1)
    smoothing_value = alpha/(k - 1)
    confidence = 1 - alpha
    above_zero = torch.zeros_like(gt).add_(smoothing_value)
    less_than_one = torch.zeros_like(gt).add_(confidence)
    smoothed = torch.where(gt == 1, less_than_one, above_zero)
    return smoothed


def main():
    n_classes = 5
    n_samples = 3
    output = torch.randn(n_samples, n_classes)
    target = torch.zeros(n_samples).random_(n_classes)
    zeros = torch.zeros(target.size(0), n_classes)
    one_hot = zeros.scatter(1, target.view(-1, 1).long(), 1)
    print(label_smoothing(one_hot, alpha=0.01))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So it gives me the following tensor.

```py
tensor([[0.0025, 0.0025, 0.0025, 0.9900, 0.0025],
        [0.9900, 0.0025, 0.0025, 0.0025, 0.0025],
        [0.9900, 0.0025, 0.0025, 0.0025, 0.0025]])
```

Currently, I'm thinking if it's possible to apply a similar approach in the case of multi-class multi-label classification? For example, imagine, I have the following target tensor.

```py
tensor([[0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

Are there any reasonable ways to smooth labels in this case? I'm thinking to somehow "subtract" a bit of value from the "ones" and scatter it among "zeros" but not sure if there are any empirical or theoretical foundations behind it at all. What do you think?